# range loop with statements

Tags: loops, range

I have a string like:

```
string = "ABCDE_FG_HILMN__OP__QRS_TUVY"
```

I have the index ("position") of a letter(M) in the middle of this string.

```
index = 11
```

I need a loop that starting from that index position print that position `+5` characters on the left and `+5` on the right. If there is a `_` it has to increment of `1` in order not to have `_` in the output and having `11` character in total in the end like:

```
FGHILMNOPQR
```

My idea is like:

```
for i in string:
 in = index
 if in != "_" andor [in-5] != "_".... andor ...
   print([in-5],[in-4],[in-3],[in-2],[in-1],[in],[in+1],[in+2],[in+3],[in+4],[in+5])
 elsif
  somethingelse
```

Comment: What specifically are you asking about?

Comment: Have you used `i` anywhere? So, what exactly is the need for you to iterate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can replace the "_" with empty string and get the 5 alphabets around M like this

```py
string = "ABCDE_FG_HILMN__OP__QRS_TUVY"

m_pos = 11 - string.count("_", 0, 11)

string.replace("_", "")[m_pos-5: m_pos+6]
```

Comment: it's a good solution but not perfect. like this after the removal of the _ the index number changes. if before the index of the M was 12, after is 10. it has to be slightly modified to take into account the number of _ that you remove from each side.

Comment: @pino in that case calculate m_pos after removal of "_" like in edited answer above

Answer (score 0):

it's a good solution but not perfect. like this after the removal of the "*" the index number changes. if before the index of the M was 12, after is 10. it has to be slightly modified to take into account the number of "*" that you remove from each side.